# When I start the project the images don't load

Tags: c#, wpf

I add an image to the window and when I start the project the image does not load.

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="188" Margin="88,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="288">
            <Image.Source>
                <BitmapImage UriSource="image1.png"/>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF2424C7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="338,24,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

I can see the image in the Visual Studio designer:

[image: Screenshot of visual studio showing that the image is shown in designer.]

---

The image file exists in the solution directory:

[image: Screenshot of Windows Explorer showing that the file exists in the solution directory.]

Comment: Does `image1.png` exist in the executing directory?

Comment: How did you add the images, resources? loose files? did you include them on the project?

Comment: yes it is in the folder.

Comment: Don't post your screenshots as answers! Edit your question instead and add them here.

Comment: @user3637574: You can try to delete it from solution explorer, and try to add existing file. Chances are, the resources out of sync

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the image is being copied to the output folder.  In Visual Studio (I only have 2010 as a reference), view the properties of the image file and make sure `Copy to Output Directory` is set to "Copy if newer".

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio 2010 properties window showing the 'Copy to Output Directory' property.]

You can check whether the image is being copied by looking in the `bin` directory.  This should be `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release` under your project directory.

Comment: i have visual studio ultimate 2013 but i dont have this option in the properties like you do. do you knok other way to solve it ? or where can i find this option ? tanks